# (PHP) Using two tables for a login query; other user not logging in?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, authentication

We were instructed to use two tables for different type of user (Super admin and Admin) which made our codes more complex than it should be.

I have a login query where I validate if the user has been disabled by a superadmin account.

However, my codes only logs in Admin accounts, and every time I try to log in a super admin account, it only shows the last Else where it says I used an invalid password/user.

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $username = $_POST ['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
        $stmt -> bindParam(1, $username);
        $stmt -> bindParam(2, $password);
        $stmt ->execute();

        $stmt2 = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM sa_users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
        $stmt2 -> bindParam(1, $username);
        $stmt2 -> bindParam(2, $password);
        $stmt2 ->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $row2 = $stmt2->fetch();

        $user = $row['username'];
        $pass = $row['password'];
        $id = $row['user_id'];
        $id2 = $row2['sa_id'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $type2 = $row2['type'];
        $user_status = $row['user_status'];

        if ($user_status == 'Disable')
        {
?>

<div class="alert">
<span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
<strong>Error!</strong> Your account has been disabled!
</div>

<?php
        } else {

            if($username==$user && $pass==$password && $type2 == 'Super_Admin')
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
                $_SESSION['sa_id'] = $id2;
                $_SESSION['type'] = $type2;
?>

<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>

<?php
            } else {
                if ($username==$user && $pass==$password && $type=='Admin')
                {

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['type'] = $type;

?>

<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>

<?php
                } else {
                    if ($username!=$user && $pass!=$password)
                    {
?>
        <div class="alert">
        <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
        <strong>Error!</strong> Wrong Password/Username.
        </div>

<?php                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing.specially not using `md5()`  PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: You have made life difficult for yourself. There is no need for 2 tables. Instead store users in one table and add a column to hold wether the use if a SuperAdmin or an Admin or a ......... etc etc

Comment: That's what I thought as well. However, we were required by the professor to do two tables. It's actually laughable. I will update the password hash as well. Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement only checks for the admin user and password.
   It misses this variable initializations:

```
$user2 = $row2['username'];
$pass2 = $row2['password'];
```

When you check for Super Admin login credentials, you check using the username and password from Admin table and not from Super Admin table.

Hence:

```
if($username==$user && $pass==$password
```

Rather Than:

```
if($username==$user2 && $pass2==$password
```

There are also lines using Admin Values when they should be from Super Admin's.

Here's the code below I updated. Not tested it yet tho. Hopefully it runs fine.

```
<?php
    include "config.php";

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))  {
                $username = $_POST ['username'];
                $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
                $stmt -> bindParam(1, $username);
                $stmt -> bindParam(2, $password);
                $stmt ->execute();

                $stmt2 = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM sa_users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
                $stmt2 -> bindParam(1, $username);
                $stmt2 -> bindParam(2, $password);
                $stmt2 ->execute();

                $row = $stmt->fetch();
                $row2 = $stmt2->fetch();

                        $user = $row['username'];
                        $pass = $row['password'];
                        $user2 = $row2['username'];
                        $pass2 = $row2['password'];
                        $id = $row['user_id'];
                        $id2 = $row2['sa_id'];
                        $type = $row['type'];
                        $type2 = $row2['type'];
                        $user_status = $row['user_status'];

                    if ($user_status == 'Disable')
                    {
                    ?>

                    <div class="alert">
                    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
                    <strong>Error!</strong> Your account has been disabled!
                    </div>

                    <?php

                    } else {

                    if($username==$user2 && $pass2==$password && $type2 == 'Super_Admin')
                    {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user2;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $pass2;
                    $_SESSION['sa_id'] = $id2;
                    $_SESSION['type'] = $type2;
                    ?>

                    <script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>

                    <?php
                    } else {


                    if ($username==$user && $pass==$password && $type=='Admin')

                    {

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['type'] = $type;

                    ?>

                    <script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>

                    <?php

                    } else {


                    if ($username!=$user && $pass!=$password)
                    {
                    ?>
                        <div class="alert">
                        <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
                        <strong>Error!</strong> Wrong Password/Username.
                        </div>

                    <?php                

                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
    ?>
        <!--end of php -->
```

Comment: It worked! I just added $user_status2 as well. 
I thought it'd accept user without calling another variable.
Thank you very much!